# R Dataframe - How to count number of rows up to a certain point?

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have data that looks something like this :

```
1   Saturday  Evening             16.2  235.84
2   Saturday  Evening             23.4  235.29
3   Saturday  Evening             29.4  232.79
4   Sunday   Evening             24.2  233.89
5   Sunday   Evening             24.2  233.66
6   Sunday   Evening             24.2  233.38
7   Sunday   Evening             24.2  232.99
8   Sunday   Evening             25.4  233.21
9   Sunday   Evening             26.8  232.37
10  Saturday    Night            25.6  231.55
11  Saturday     Night           24.4  231.19
12  Saturday     Night           24.4  231.63
13  Saturday     Night           24.4  231.71
14  Sunday     Night             25.2  231.23
15  Sunday     Night             25.2  231.23
14  Saturday     Night             25.2  231.23
15  Saturday    Night             25.2  231.23
15  Sunday    Night             25.2  231.23

df = structure(list(V2 = c("Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday"), V3 = c("Evening", "Evening", "Evening", 
"Evening", "Evening", "Evening", "Evening", "Evening", "Evening", 
"Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
"Night", "Night"), V4 = c(16.2, 23.4, 29.4, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 
24.2, 25.4, 26.8, 25.6, 24.4, 24.4, 24.4, 25.2, 25.2, 25.2, 25.2, 
25.2), V5 = c(235.84, 235.29, 232.79, 233.89, 233.66, 233.38, 
232.99, 233.21, 232.37, 231.55, 231.19, 231.63, 231.71, 231.23, 
231.23, 231.23, 231.23, 231.23)), .Names = c("V2", "V3", "V4", 
"V5"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data only includes only Saturdays and Sundays, so it's not continuous (as in, data between the previous Sunday and the beginning of the next Saturday/the weekdays is missing). The number of data for each weekend varies, so I need to count how many observations are in each of the Saturday Sunday sets. Assuming the data starts on Saturday to Sunday, then goes to the next set of Saturday-Sunday again, how can I count each set of data and store it in a vector?

Edit : For example, using the data above, my desired output would be a vector of values containing : [9, 6, 3]

Comment: Please share your desired output.

Comment: A crude way: `r = rle(df$V2); tapply(r$lengths, rep(1:length(r$values), each=2, length.out=length(r$values)), sum)` or `with(r, lengths[c(TRUE, FALSE)] + lengths[c(FALSE, TRUE)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `dplyr` solution, where `V2` is your current column of days:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(x = lag(cumsum((V2 == 'Sunday' & lead(V2) == 'Saturday')), default = 0)) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(z = n()) %>%
  select(z)
```

This yields

```
      z
  <int>
1     9
2     6
3     3
```

Comment: Thank you for this great solution!

Comment: I'm trying to modify your solution to do the same thing for weekdays, but the problem now is my weekdays data starts on Thursday instead of Monday for the first set and it also doesn't end on Friday for the last set. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Never mind! Your solution works even when the data doesn't start on Monday or ends on Friday!

Answer (score 0):

I like using the package data.table for things like this. Below is an example.

```
  install.packages ("data.table")
  library (data.table)

  foo = structure(list(V2 = c("Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
                       "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Saturday", 
                       "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Saturday", 
                       "Saturday", "Sunday"), V3 = c("Evening", "Evening", "Evening", 
                                                     "Evening", "Evening", "Evening", "Evening", "Evening", "Evening", 
                                                     "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", "Night", 
                                                     "Night", "Night"), V4 = c(16.2, 23.4, 29.4, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 
                                                                               24.2, 25.4, 26.8, 25.6, 24.4, 24.4, 24.4, 25.2, 25.2, 25.2, 25.2, 
                                                                               25.2), V5 = c(235.84, 235.29, 232.79, 233.89, 233.66, 233.38, 
                                                                                             232.99, 233.21, 232.37, 231.55, 231.19, 231.63, 231.71, 231.23, 
                                                                                             231.23, 231.23, 231.23, 231.23)), .Names = c("V2", "V3", "V4", 
                                                                                                                                          "V5"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")

  foo <- as.data.table (foo) #convert to a datatable
  nrow (subset (foo, V2 == "Saturday")) #count how many rows are Saturday
  nrow (subset (foo, V2 == "Sunday")) #count how many rows are Sunday
  nrow (subset (foo, V2 == "Saturday" & V3 == "Evening")) #count how many rows are Saturday Evening
  nrow (subset (foo, V2 == "Saturday" & V3 == "Evening" | V3 == "Night")) #count how many rows are Saturday Evening and Night
```